# Action not working if UITabBar has more than 5 items

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbar

I want to perform an action when the user clicked on some tabs in UITabBar without opening another view. For example, setting tab or share.
Here is what I did :

```
class ViewTabBarController: UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        print("do something")
    }
}
```

This code works fine if the UITabBar has just 5 items. 
But the problem here is that if UITabBar has more than 5 items those that are under the "More Tab" did not call the tabBar() function when clicked.

Comment: P.S: keep in mind that adding more than 5 items into a tabbar would *not* be a good practice. https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7379/alternatives-to-more-tab-button-in-a-uitabbar

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation description of the didSelect method of UITabBarControllerDelegate:

> Tells the delegate that the user selected an item in the tab bar.

What that means is that the method is called when the user taps on one of the buttons in the bar.  When you have a 'more' button then that is the button in the tab bar so tapping 'more' fires that method.

The view controllers in the 'more' section are actually processed in a different way involving the use of a UINavigationController.  With these views they don't have a button in the tab bar and therefore this even is not fired.